# How to cover myself if user inputs a non number in my random number guessing game

Tags: c++

Need help figuring out how to cover myself in case the user enters anything other than a number.

I've tried ending my if/elseif statements with an else to cover if the number is ! <,>,or = to. Doesn't seem to work and I kinda see why logically but can't figure out an alternative.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int number, guess;
        srand(time(NULL));
        number = rand()%100+1;
     do
    {
       cout << "Guess a number from 1-100.\n";
       cin >> guess;

     if (guess < number)
        cout << "Too low. Try again.\n";

      else if(guess > number)
        cout << "Too High. Try again.\n";

      else if (guess == number)
        cout << "Nice job. You got it right on.\n";

      else
          cout << "Ummm...A number please. Let's try again.\n";

    }while (guess != number);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the user input in as a string rather than a number. Then check that the string contains a valid numeric value and then convert to a number:

```
#include <string>

std::string GuessText;
unsigned long GuessNumber;
size_t NumberStart;

cin >> GuessText;

// check that user entered a valid number
NumberStart = GuessText.find_first_of("0123456789");
if (NumberStart == string::npos)
  cout << "Ummm...A number please. Let's try again.\n";
else 
  {
    // get the substring that contains the number
    GuessText = GuessText.substr(PositionStart);

    // convert string to number
    GuessNumber = std::stoul(GuessText, nullptr, 0);

    ....
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried your method and im getting an error with my if statements. I think its because im now trying to compare a string to an int. When i change both the variables to strings. I get the program to run. Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind...Bad idea on my part...Program not good. It now chooses numbers and letters randomly. Totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using isnan to check if the input value is a number. It not, have a while loop to keep re-asking for input untill the user inputs a number.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new to this and greatly appreciate the help. I unfortunately have not heard of isnan and after reading up on it I understand what it does but do not know how to write it out correctly. Could you help me out again.

Comment: @EdwardNieves Edited my answer. I haven't used c++ in a while, but this should work.

Comment: Thank you. I tried writing it the way you have it and im still getting the same problem. I dont know. Thank you again.

Comment: @EdwardNieves the reason you get an error is because guess is of type int.I totally forgot that. I am currently working on writing code for a working solution. But itll be basically like this: use a string to get input>loop over characters of the string and make sure they are all digits (using ascii values)>if true=>turn string to int/if false=> ask for input again. The issue is that input buffers in c and c++ are a pain in the a** and I havent used either languages in a LONG while.